# I can't display the output of the `readline` function from Julia on VScode using Jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, jupyter

When a try to get an imput like this:

x  = readline()

Always got the massege
[UndefVarError: UndefVarError: execute_msg not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyesH.png)

Comment: Works for me using Visual Studio Code 1.60.1 with Julia 1.6.2 and IJulia v1.23.2 on Windows 10.
A tiny input window for stdin will open up at the top of my VSCode. I can enter a string and press Enter to confirm.
Maybe try again with Julia 1.6.2 to check if this is a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2471.

Generally, the native notebook functionality isn't 100% en par with Jupyter.